# jQuery getting item values

Tags: jquery

I'm making a form on a wordpress blog that uses ajax.
I'm trying to grab some values from a form and when I call:

`var name = jQuery("#name").val();`

it's empty. That is unless i hardcode the value like:

`<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="myname"/>` why is that?

Comment: When are you running your `var name = jQuery("#name").val();`? On a click? On DOM ready?

Comment: Because some one should "type" into the text box :)

Comment: Can you post your `HTML` of form generated by browser ? May be it's empty.

Comment: Probably the data is fetched (you say ajax) AFTER you set the var name,

Comment: lol ok i was doing it before the click instead of after! j08691 make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you running your `var name = jQuery("#name").val();`? On a click? On DOM ready? Make sure the data is there before you try to get it ;)

Comment: No, it is the answer. I was calling for the values before the user clicks the submit button making the values null.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi - it was. then the OP realized this solved the problem and asked me to post as the answer.